# How the user entered by login page or register page?

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

I have an App that requires login:

1. If the user has `registered` before then he uses `login` .
2. and if he has not `registered` before , he should `registration` after `register` then he will `redirected` to page .

Now i want to know that how the user entered that page by `login` or `registration` page?

Notice: In that page reset every 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to save if the user is already registered or not. When someone registered, put a boolean to true on the sharedpreference

If your registration activity is your launcher activity, then before displaying the view check on your SharedPreference if your boolean registered is set to true, if not continue on the register activity, if it's true start your Login activity

I do like this, I don't know if it's the better way

Comment: Thanks @ agonist_ .I use boolean in SharedPreference then remove that in onDestroy().